# Catching exception for server not available

Tags: spring-boot

I am new in spring boot and programming world .I am trying to post data on another server. I am using rest template to do that. I want to catch an exception when the server  is not available .I am not sure how to do that .It would be helpful if anyone can just guide me where to look .I find so many examples but its getting more confusing.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @Error Handler for this.You can use in your controller class to look around how this works when called.

```
   @PostMapping("/hello")
   public void hello(String msg)
   {
       RestTemplate restTemplate= new RestTemplate();
       HttpEntity<String>reqEntity= new HttpEntity<>(msg);
       restTemplate.postForEntity(" paste your server url here", reqEntity, String.class);
    
   }
   
   
   @ExceptionHandler(ConnectException.class)
   @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
   public void func()
    {
       System.out.println("I am not able to connect");
   }
```

As you mentioned the server is not running so it will be handled by below mentioned function func on which @Exception handler is declared.You can read on @Exception handler.Certainly there are many different ways to do it.